# How do you remove all the alphabetic characters from a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string containg alphabetic characters, for example:

1. **254.69 meters**
2. **26.56 cm**
3. **23.36 inches**
4. **100.85 ft**

I want to remove all the alphabetic characters (units) from the above mentioned strings so that I can call the `double.Parse()` method.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

This should work:

```
// add directive at the top 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string numberOnly = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9.]", "")
```

Comment: Probably want to preserve any sign: `"[^0-9.+-]"`

Comment: @BillP3rd - but wants to remove alphabates and string is of units with number. do you really think its required ?

Comment: Thanks Pranay for the solution. BillP3rd , at present i don't need +- signs , but thanks for the update, may be in future I do want to preserve the signs.

Comment: This solution does not play well with localizations for countries where the decimals are after a '.'

Comment: this remove the dot for me e.g. 24.99 somechracter -> 2499

Comment: Regex is found here... using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Answer (score 26):

You should be able to solve this using Regex. Add the following reference to your project:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

after that you can use the following:

```
string value = Regex.Replace(<yourString>, "[A-Za-z ]", "");
double parsedValue = double.Parse(value);
```

Assuming you have only alphabetic characters and space as units.

Comment: This will fail in a lot of exceptions

Comment: How so given my assumption of only needing to remove alphabetic characters and spaces? @LeandroBardelli

Comment: alphabetic characters are not only letters.

Comment: My solution will work for all the examples given in the question. As far as I know, there is no unit containing a special character. True, that is an assumption I am making. And there are better answers than mine, such as the accepted answer. None the less, my solution will not throw any exception given the examples in the question....

Answer (score 14):

Using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

string input ="57.20000 KG ";
string output = new string(input.Where(c=>(Char.IsDigit(c)||c=='.'||c==',')).ToArray());
```

Comment: It's only a little thing: this solution removes the dependency on System.Text.RegularExpressions - which is not commonly used in the current application I am working on.

Answer (score 4):

Hi another solution is:

```
// add directive at the top 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string s = "24,99";
string numberOnly = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9,-]+", "")
```

This solution will not remove the dot e.g. question from user1804084:

*this remove the dot for me e.g. 24.99 somechracter -> 2499*

However it can still be convertet to a double where adding and subtraction works as normal.

Answer (score 3):

The Regex, and Vlad's LINQ answers cover the solution well.  And are both good options.

I had a similar problem, but I also wanted to only explicitly strip letters, and not to strip white space or etc, with this variant.

I also wanted it usable as below.  Any of the other solutions could be packaged in a similar manner.

```
public static string StripAlpha(this string self)
{
    return new string( self.Where(c => !Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray() );
}

public static string StripNonNumeric(this string self)
{
    // Use Vlad's LINQ or the Regex Example
    return new string(self.Where(c=>(Char.IsDigit(c)||c=='.'||c==',')).ToArray()) ;  // See Vlad's

}
```

This would then be used such as:

```
var newString = someString.StripAlpha();
var newString2 = someString.StripNonNumeric();
```

Answer (score -2):

Use CharMatcher API from Google's Guava library:

```
String magnitudeWithUnit = "254.69 meter";
String magnitude = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z').or(inRange('A', 'Z')).removeFrom(magnitudeWithUnit);
```

Do static-import `CharMatcher.inRange(..)`. You can trim the results for trailing space.

Comment: Really wouldn't recommend an external dependency for something that is supported by c#/BCL