# parse selected text to string ignoring chars

Tags: c#, winforms

Im taking a `selected.text` which  can equal 123t, and id like to just take the 123 and insert it into a `string`. the `selected.text` can also simply equal 54, or 256, but occasionally it will have a letter. Im unsure of which what to select or parse to remove the letter. i tried to do something convoluted like this as i saw similar questions on SE,

```
string cat;
   int dog;        
   cat = txtFrame.Text;
   dog = int.Parse(cat.Substring(cat.IndexOf("")));
   Frame = dog.ToString();
```

`Frame` is the string i would like it to end up in.

Comment: Please explain if the numbers are always consecutive or if you have a letters mixed with numbers

Comment: @Steve numbers always first, but length of numbers can be 2-3 and letters can change length as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably best done with Regex

```
string test = "123t";
Match m = Regex.Match(test, @"\d+");
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

If an eventual sign is possible in your string then you could use an expanded form of the pattern

```
 Regex.Match(test, @"[-+]?\d+")
```

Comment: just out of interest ... does your answer preserve +/- sign ... not sure about \d ... could look it up but it's always better to get an expert's opinion ;0)

Comment: No, d+ matches only numbers. Regex.Match(test, @"[-+]?\d+") to preserve an eventual sign

Comment: Cool. I prefer your answer :0)

Answer (score 0):

From the following post ...

[How do you remove all the alphabetic characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624332/how-do-you-remove-all-the-alphabetic-characters-from-a-string)

`Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9.+-]", "")`

@Steve's answer is better!

Here's a good resource for RegEx ... http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: this simply just removes all alphabetic chars? if so sounds just right