# c# Windows Forms Application clear only text

Tags: c#

i have a task, where user enters numbers, and when you press button, it gives you out the sum of them, but if you type in some text, message box pops up with yes and no, if you press yes, then all text clears (not the numbers). So my question is, how can i only clear letters, but not numbers? I am not very good at this so i am going crazy trying to thing of this!

```
private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        if(IsAllLetters(textBox1.Text) == true)
        {
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += (int)char.GetNumericValue(textBox1.Text[i]);
        }
        label2.Text = "Summa:               " + sum;
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete all letters??", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
               //do something else

            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //do something else
            }
        }

    }
       public static bool IsAllLetters (string s)
    {
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove all the alphabetic characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624332/how-do-you-remove-all-the-alphabetic-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [ask] a good question. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: It helps a lot to show what you already have, it allows us to give a more specific answer.

Comment: I entered the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other's have mentioned, this isn't very clear. Although I think I understand your issue, I can't relate it to the context without an example of what you've tried already.

Anyway, you can use regex for this.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then, assuming you've stored the input as a variable, let's say "userInput"

```
Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(userInput, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty));
```

This will return a integer of the extracted numbers. I'll update my answer once you've updated your question.

EDIT: Literally as soon as I posted this you updated it. My above code will still work, if you assign textBox1.Text to a variable.

```
    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string userInput = textBox1.Text;
        int sum = 0;
        if (IsAllLetters(userInput) == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += (int)char.GetNumericValue(userInput[i]);
            }
            label2.Text = "Summa:               " + sum;
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete all letters??", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                userInput = Regex.Replace(userInput, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
                for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
                {
                    sum += (int)char.GetNumericValue(userInput[i]);
                }
                label2.Text = "Summa:               " + sum;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //do something else
            }
        }

    }
    public static bool IsAllLetters(string s)
    {
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This example checks, if the char is a number.
Maybe it is useful for you.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string inputText = "John12Fitzgerald34Kennedy";
        StringBuilder returnText = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char singleChar in inputText)
        {
            if ((int)singleChar >= 0x30 && (int)singleChar <= 0x39)
                returnText.Append(singleChar);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(returnText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```